# Why is my success.html page getting a 404 error when I submit a test transaction through Stripe?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to perform a test transaction using stripe with a Django web project.

The following code is my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse
from . models import Product, OrderDetail
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponseNotFound
import stripe
import json

# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    print(products)
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {'products': products})


def detail(request, id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    stripe_publishable_key = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
    return render(request, 'myapp/detail.html', {'product': product, 'stripe_publishable_key': stripe_publishable_key})


@csrf_exempt
def create_checkout_session(request, id):
    request_data = json.loads(request.body)
    product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
        amount=int(product.price * 100),
        currency='usd',
        payment_method_types=['card'],
    )
    checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        customer_email=request_data['email'],
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[
            {
                'price_data': {
                    'currency': 'usd',
                    'product_data': {
                        'name': product.name,
                    },
                    'unit_amount': int(product.price * 100)
                },
                'quantity': 1,
            }
        ],
        mode='payment',
        success_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('success')) +
        "?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
        cancel_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('failed')),
    )

    print(checkout_session)

    order = OrderDetail(
        customer_email=request_data['email'],
        product=product,
        stripe_payment_intent=checkout_session['payment_intent'],
        amount=int(product.price)
    )

   # checkout_session.payment_intent = intent
    order.save()

    return JsonResponse({'sessionId': checkout_session.id})


def payment_success_view(request):
    session_id = request.GET.get('session_id')
    if not session_id:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()

    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    session = stripe.checkout.Session.retrieve(session_id)
    order = get_object_or_404(
        OrderDetail, stripe_payment_intent=session.payment_intent)
    order.has_paid = True
    order.save()

    return render(request, 'myapp/success.html', {'order': order},)


def payment_failed_view(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/failed.html')
```

The stripe transaction goes through successfully before giving a 404 error when being redirected to success.html

I have reviewed my views.py file and also the urls.py files to verify the syntax. This is all in line with the source code provided by the learning portal I am following.

I presume either there has been some update to the Stripe API code that I'm missing, or I have some silly error somewhere else that I'm unaware of.

How can I begin to troubleshoot this?

Comment: A 404 after the redirect clearly indicates a missing page. So, just make sure the page you redirect to exists.

Comment: I checked the page existed and confirmed the name. There is a new feature to the Stripe payment gateway that is not covered in the version of lesson I'm following.

There is an issue with the payment_intent feature and it seems to not provide a value. I corrected this with a Null=True command in my models.py. Which worked until I tried to load the success page and I encountered this issue and it seems that without a payment_intent value the succes page will not load?

Comment: You return a `HttpResponseNotFound` if `session_id` is missing. If this is not what you want, then change this part of the code.